__field_bcount_part(BufferLength,DataLength) PVOID DataBuffer;
anyone can help explain how this statement works:
__field_bcount_part(BufferLength,DataLength) PVOID  DataBuffer;

Found the definition of __field_bcount_part:
#define __field_bcount_part(size,init) __notnull __byte_writableTo(size) __byte_readableTo(init)


tell your compiler to stop after the preprocess step to see the actual expanded output. All compilers can do that

My bad, my eyes missed the comma in size,init. It looks like a call using the macro passing PVOID as __byte_writable and DataBuffer as __byte_readableTo, but it is hard to tell what will happen to it without more of the source.
